# Connection of Epson projector (LW373) does not work in Ubuntu (Kde Plasma + NVidia)

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Good morning,
I have a serious problem: I have to connect my computer (Ubuntu / Kde Plasma 22.04) to an EPSON projector (PT-LW373 WXGA) via VGA cable + HDMI adapter, as soon as connected the image appears projected for 4-5 seconds and then goes out, after 10 seconds it reappears and goes out again, cyclically. I wouldn't call it a flickering, but rather as if the automatic recognition is not stable. I am now using the proprietary NVidia drivers (I have a GP108M - GEForce MX250) (but the problem also stays with the Xsever-xorg nouveau).

Being so unstable, I cannot see in detail what are the parameters set by the system for the projector (resolution / Hz ...), looking around it could be due to the fact that linux does not read the EDID correctly (but I did not understand what it is).

Unfortunately, I do not have access (7/24) to the projector because it is in a room where I have to teach. So I can't stand to try various solutions or advice right away. If anyone has an idea, on Wednesday I will try to solve the problem. (I also thought about changing the cable, it seems that sometimes it may be that, even if the projector is only seen for 5 seconds).

some data of my system:

```
~\ >>> sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1920,1080
       resources: irq:139 memory:64000000-64ffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:7000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP108M [GeForce MX250]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:148 memory:65000000-65ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff memory:60000000-61ffffff ioport:6000(size=128) memory:66000000-6607ffff


~\ >>> inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel WhiskeyLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics 620] driver: i915 v: kernel
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108M [GeForce MX250] driver: nvidia v: 515.65.01
  Device-3: Chicony HD Webcam type: USB driver: uvcvideo
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.3 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa gpu: i915
    resolution: 3440x1440~50Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 620 (WHL GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 22.0.5
```

~\ >>> nvidia-smi
Mon Oct 31 15:17:56 2022
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 11.7     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   38C    P8    N/A /  N/A |      4MiB /  2048MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1480      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                  4MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Open Nvidia X Server Settings, make sure the "high performance (Nvidia)" profile is selected and reboot.

Comment: thanks. I look at the Nvidia X Server Settings, I found two possible modifications: [1] in "PRIME Profiles", the option between "NVIDIA Performance mode" and "NVIDIA On-Demand" (the last one was selected). [2] in "PowerMizer" the settings of PowerMizer were "Preferred Mode: Auto", I could change to "Adaptive" or "Prefer Maximum Performance". Any tips? (thanx).

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in the terminal then plug in and turn on your projector. The command gives real time out put for conflict and errors.
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Give this artical a read also...
https://stackify.com/linux-logs/
Also make sure all cables adapters are in good working order
I would also sugest turning off screen energy saving ... Suspend session..basically any thing that has to do with putting your monitor's to sleep/suspension and logging you out after inactivity but dont forget to turn them all back on after wards.
I hope this helps good luck.

Comment: thank you Steve. I will try this!